# Rectangular Flag Emojis for react native

Tags: react-native, emoji, flags, picker, actionsheet

As you all must know, the classic emojis that are used are the ones that have `flapping` flags.
I need to show the flags along with their countries in `picker label`, but the `rectangular` flags I want.

I have found a package that returns a rectangular flag, but it returns it as an `object` and since an object can't be passed as text in `Picker.Item label`, I am getting displayed `[object Object]` instead of those rectangular flags.

If anyone can give an alternate package that has rectangular flags as emojis or a way to an object to be rendered as text, I would forever be in his/her debt.

Thanks.

Comment: There is no option available to use the rectangular flags, woooow

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Unicode characters of country flags to display them as text.
https://snack.expo.io/@maskedman/flag-labels

Comment: I can. But emojis that I get with it, are of flapping flags. I want it rectangular.